# PHP Download file corrupt (zip & word)

Tags: php, zip, docx, doc

I'm having script that get file from server but every time I click on a download link. It gave me a corrupt word or zip file which need to be repaired.

Here is code:

```
    if(!$file_download=@fopen(_get_dir().'/'.$_GET['file'],'rb')){
      die("403 - Access denied");
    } else {

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_GET['file']."\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-length:".(string)(filesize(_get_dir().'/'.$_GET['file'])));

    sleep(1);

    set_time_limit(0);
    readfile($file_download);
    }
```

I have read and tried many similar questions but it just not works. Thanks.

**PROBLEM SOLVED! I just remove all BOM out of PHP files (in Include too) and it works!**

Comment: Make sure you aren't echoing/printing any whitespace (or indeed anything but the contents of readfile(), have no BOM marker in your script, etc. Openthe file in a txet editor to check, and also to see if you are getting any plaintext PHP error messages

Comment: Try to edit the docx with a text editor to see what's in it. Then please post the beginning of that document

Comment: @edi9999 I'm sure docx or doc or zip is ok, checked twice before uploading.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks but I use Notepad++ -> Unicode without BOM

Comment: Doesn't mean that you aren't echoing/printing anything before of after the readfile(), or even have a `?> <?php` that will inject whitespace into the output stream

Comment: @DucViet321 I meant the downloaded docx, not the one you upload which of course I hope is not corrupt :-)

Comment: @edi9999 Makes sense =) Ok, I see the differents but don't know what to do next...

Comment: @edi9999 Oops, sorry, I opened one in ASCI and Unicode for the other, now I changed both to Unicode and hard to see any different though Open downloaded one is corrupted :(

Comment: than maybe try to open them with a hex editor. You could also diff the two files  (eg `diff file1 file2`)

Comment: I found it! There is BOM in my downloaded file!!! While searching for the solution hope you guys can give me a quick answer :)

Comment: If there's a BOM in your downloaded file, then check any files that are included by your download script to see if they have been saved with a BOM header

Answer (score 0):

try this method, hope helps. 
filePath -> Is the path to the file ex: C:\files.

fileName -> Is the name of the file with his extension ex: resume.doc

```
private function GetHeadersForDownload ($filePath, $fileName)
    {
        $data = file_get_contents($filePath . '/' . $fileName);

        $extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $mime = $this->GetMIMEType($extension);

        // Generate the server headers

            header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Pragma: public');
            header("Content-Length: " . strlen($data));

        exit($data);
    }

private function GetMIMEType($ext)
    {
        $mimes = array(
            'zip' => 'application/x-zip'
            'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'txt' => 'text/plain',
            'doc' => 'application/msword',
            'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'word' => 'application/msword'

        );
        // Set a default mime if we can't find it
        if (!isset($mimes[$ext]))
            return 'application/octet-stream';
        else
            return $mimes[$ext];
    }
```

Comment: One thing, for windows 8 and 7 the path can't be c: .